# UFW setup for OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, firewall, openvpn, ufw

I set up OpenVPN server on one Ubuntu machine and I am connecting to it via another Ubuntu machine. However, the VPN works only when the server firewall (ufw) is disabled. That is I can connect when the firewall is on but I get timeout if I try to connect to some local server from the client (or browse). Meanwhile, the server logs in `/var/log/syslog`:

> Jun 30 16:33:09 user kernel: [543227.015571] [UFW BLOCK] IN=tap0
>   OUT=eth0 MAC=0e:*********:00 SRC=10.8.0.4 DST=208.67.220.220
>   LEN=69 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=10228 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7401 DPT=53
>   LEN=49

I added to the firewall

> ufw allow 1194/udp

also tried

> ufw allow from 10.8.0.4

but no luck.

The DST IP in the error message is different from my server wlan0 IP. Running openvpn on the server adds  10.8.0.0 tap0. On the client it adds 10.8.0.4 tap0

Answer (score 1):

When running a firewall like ufw, please consider [enabling ip forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161346/how-to-configure-ufw-to-allow-ip-forwarding), otherwise the clients will only be able to connect to the server, but not to other LAN servers. [[0]](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN)