# SMTP IP forwarding to another machine

Tags: networking, iptables, ufw, port-forwarding

Apologies if this is a silly mistake this is the first time ive had to set up port forwarding. I have two  machines I have one machine set up as a DMZ (192.168.0.67) when all traffic inbound will hit first. I have configured a second machine to be an email server (192.168.0.78).

When I connect to the mail server from the dmz server or another machine via telnet I get 220 response from the smtp server. So I know the server is running and accessible from outside the mail server.

I edited my /etc/ufw/before.rules
to try and forward all traffic on port 25 to the dmz machine to the mail server I have set up. I added the following lines near the top of the file above the *filter section

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING --protocol tcp --destination 192.168.0.67 --dport 25 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.78:25
-A POSTROUTING --protocol tcp --destination 192.168.0.78 --dport 25 --jump SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.67
COMMIT
```

After this I made sure UFW would reload successfully and rebooted the DMZ machine for good measure.

Unfortunately when i telnet to port 25 on the dmz server I don't get a response. I have read quite a few articles and watched a few videos and i cant seem to see what i have done incorrectly.

I checked ip forwarding was enabled with
`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` and the result was 1.

I also ran

```
sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:25,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:192.168.0.78:25
```

Which worked and allowed me to use telnet to connect on port 25 on the dmz server and receive the reply from he the mail server as I wanted. Which makes me think the problem is just that I have done something wrong with the rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Also I do not see any mention of a version of Ubuntu in your question.

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for your suggestions I have modified it take them into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked out what the problem was it thanks to this answer
[How to configure UFW to allow IP Forwarding?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161346/how-to-configure-ufw-to-allow-ip-forwarding?rq=1)
my `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY` was set to `DROP` not `ACCEPT` in /etc/default/ufw

Changing it and it works as expected.